# Unable to edit/delete/move /etc/my.cnf - Permission denied

Tags: mysql, ssh, my.cnf

I am trying to edit /etc/my.cnf as root user via ssh and I get following error while trying to save it

I ma making changes to my.cnf as I want to tweak some values in my.cnf to meet Magento requirement like changing key_buffer_size= to higher value (128M). I assigned the value 128M to key_buffer_size= and tried to save it and then got an error.

> "Error writing /etc/my.cnf: Permission denied"

I cant even restart MySQL successfully.

```
[root@flourish ~]# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I can even delete or replace it with the fresh one. I tried uninstalling MySQL and re-installing but nothing worked. Permission -rw-r--r-- and Owner/Group root/root

I hope there is some answer to this problem.

Comment: How do you know you're root?

Comment: I ma using username as root which I created while setting up the server. 

visudo
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

Comment: Please edit your question to specify exactly what you are doing, then.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton I have added more details. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has the file perhaps been made immutable with chattr? lsattr should tell you:

```
$ lsattr my.cnf
----i----------- my.cnf
```

would be the output for an immutable file.

Comment: Hi, Here is the output.
`----i--------e- my.cnf`

Comment: Immutable it is :) Can be fixed with sudo chattr -i my.cnf

Comment: Hi Dennis, That did a trick. I am still having some issue installing web services `No package httpd available.
No package mod_ssl available.` Is it something to do with immutable files?

Comment: You might want to open a separate question for that and include your yum config.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will open another thread. Great Day

Comment: Is advisable to run `sudo chattr +i my.cnf` after editing the files, to protect it again?

Comment: No, I do not consider that advisable at all.